# Replace all \\ with / in files and subdirs

Tags: linux, bash

i need a quick command (linux or windows) to replace every \\ with a /, and all tries with sed failed because of the /. 
(I already tried `find . -name '*.*' -exec sed -i 's/\\///g' {} \;`, but i think it failed with the "/".

Comment: I meant \\, but it was replaced :(

Comment: You tagged Python here. I believe that if you actually use the `os` module, this *should* all be taken care of for you when providing the respective path on that platform.

Comment: Also, for whatever case you are doing this for, there are several solutions out there that do this for you in many different ways. Have you tried all solutions out there?

Comment: Can you post the error you got?

Comment: There would have been a `sed` syntax error for the unescaped literal slash.

Comment: The error just was "no such file or directory"

Comment: @tripleee: No, it said it replaced some things, but it didn't

Comment: @idjaw: No, the problem is  a "\\\\", what works on windows, but not on linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.*' -type f -exec sed -i 's:\\\\:/:g' {} \;
```

You need to escape each backslash, and using a colon or comma as separators is generally recommended when making replacements with forward-slash. However, escaping the forward slash works too:

```
find . -name '*.*' -type f -exec sed -i 's/\\\\/\//g' {} \;
```

As pointed out in comments the OS module is probably what you really need to look at.

**Edit:** thanks to @tripleee for reminding me of the `-type f` line, which limits it to files, rather than including the current directory.

Also, I copied the syntax `*.*` from the OP but in general it isn't helpful. `*` alone is usually what you want, since files aren't guaranteed to have a dot in their name. Assuming you were happy to include files not containing a dot, the simplest thing to do here is have no `-name` at all:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's:\\\\:/:g' {} \;
```

Comment: @tdelaney OP doesn't want that, they've made it clear in the title and comment they want two backslashes to be replaced, not one.

Comment: @tdelaney I quote OP: `I meant \\, but it was replaced :(`

Comment: Okay, I sse. I assumed that comment referred to the code example and that OP had fixed it by the time I got here.

Comment: I get an error when I try this `Cannot process . :That's not a normal file ` (I hope I translated it right)

Comment: You'll want to add a `-type f` to the `find` command line, before the `-exec`.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks! I'd meant to look up that switch and add it but forgot. It's now in the answer.